# How does probability rate increase in this situation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have $n$ items and I pick $3$ items from it and perform some operation. I know that the success rate of this operation is $x\%$ when I have only $3$ items. But, in order to increase the success rate of the operation, I increase my $n$ value and perform the operation on three randomly chosen items under the following condition. I am able to prove this empirically. But I have been trying a long time to prove it mathematically. Can someone help with it?

Conditions: the randomly chosen tuples from the list $n$ cannot have repetitions of pairs and triples. (I am sorry if this doesn't make sense) for example:

If $n=7$, I have $I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4,I_5,I_6,I_7$ items. My chosen tuples set is

$$(I_1,I_2,I_3); \quad (I_1,I_4,I_5); \quad (I_1,I_6,I_7); \quad (I_2,I_4,I_6); \quad (I_2,I_5,I_7); \quad (I_3,I_4,I_7); \quad (I_3,I_5,I_6)$$

[This graph shows the increase in success rate with increase in $n$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNRfV.png)

For example, following are the set of tuples formed when $n=7$ and $n=9$. I apply the operation on each of the tuple and declare success if any of the tuple return a true value. For the following list, we can see that the rate is increased just because of the inclusion of [1,8,9] tuple when $n=9$. I want to prove this mathematically.

-bash-4.4pythonenumerateset.py 7
[[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,6,7],[2,4,6],[2,5,7],[3,4,7],[3,5,6]]

−bash−4.4 python enumerate_set.py 9 
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 6, 7], [1, 8, 9], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 7], [3, 5, 6]]

Comment: This is not clear.  Are the successes of a $3-$ tuple independent of each other even if there is an overlap?  And what does success mean if you try multiple triples?  Obviously your chances of a single win increase if you try more often...is that all you are asking?

Comment: I am not sure if the success is independent. There should be some dependence because I am able to see a increase in success rate. I apply the same operation on each tuple. Success is if I get true value out of the operation. I agree success increase with multiple trials. But I am not asking for that. My question is how is the success rate increasing when I have this kind of overlap. I can show a graph from my experiments if this explanation is not clear.

Comment: Does properties of item itself changes when you increasing the size of n?For n = 7 you have chosen $ (I_1,I_2,I_3)$ but what if you increases the size to  n =9 by adding I_10 & I_11 and again perform your experiment on $ (I_1,I_2,I_3)$ Does the success rate changes???

Comment: For example, following are the set of tuples formed when $n=7$ and $n=9$. I apply the operation on each of the tuple and declare success if any of the tuple return a true value. For the following list, we can see that the rate is increased just because of the inclusion of [1,8,9] tuple when n=9. I want to prove this mathematically. -bash-4.4$ python enumerate_set.py 7
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 7], [3, 5, 6]]
-bash-4.4$ python enumerate_set.py 9
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 6, 7], [1, 8, 9], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 7], [3, 4, 7], [3, 5, 6]]

Comment: I think it would greatly improve your chances of getting an answer if you included some context. At least for me it's not clear so far what are the mechanics of this process.

Comment: Main aim is to prove that we don't need to perform "the operation" on all the n items. Instead if we pick 3 items and perform the operation, it has "chances" of giving higher success. Suppose my operation is "bit-wise AND", instead of performing an AND operation on all the n items, a randomly picked  3 items from the list under the conditions would give me the desired result.